# Why does passing null in `date` argument when initializing a date results in previous day?

Tags: javascript, date

What is the logic behind this behavior? Why does passing null results in a previous day?

```
JSON.stringify(new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 0, null)));      // "2017-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"
JSON.stringify(new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 0)));            // "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
JSON.stringify(new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 0, undefined))); // null
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date). When more than 1 argument is passed to the constructor, [*ToNumber*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) is called on each value, and `ToNumber(null)` converts to `+0`. So:

```
Date.UTC(2018, 0, null)
```

is the same as:

```
Date.UTC(2018, 0, 0)
```

Since there is no 0th of January, it goes to the previous day, 31 December of the previous year. This behaviour is used in a common technique for getting the last day of a month and also calculating the number of days in a month.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It indeed sheds light on this weird phenomenon, yet this is so unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I assume *null* is converted to a number (0).

The *day* parameter of the function should take an integer between 1 and 31. But after testing it, you can also pass zero and negative numbers in, and it will 'subtract' the days from the date. For example, passing in 0 subtracts 1 day, -1 subracts 2 days etc.

On the other hand, *undefined* cannot be converted to a number:

```
Number(null) // => 0
Number(undefined) // => NaN
```

Comment: Re: "*The day parameter of the function should take an integer between 1 and 31*" there is no such restriction, any number will do.